# .Net Core Async Method for Azure Services

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, async-await

I've created an ASP Net Core (2.0) Web Application with Azure Connected Services, when testing on localhost it works perfect, but when published to IIS it throws the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. SocketException: An error occurred during the connection attempt because the connected party did not respond properly after a period of time, or an error occurred in the connection established since the connected host could not respond 40.112.254.71:443

I post a txt file from view to controller and send to Azure Service for analysis, this is the post method:

```
[HttpPost("Analyze_v2")]
    public JsonResult Analyze_v2(IFormFile archivo)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(archivo.OpenReadStream()))
        {
            while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
                result.Add(reader.ReadLine());
        }

        List<TextAnalyzeModel> data = new List<TextAnalyzeModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
        {
            TextAnalyzeModel model = new TextAnalyzeModel();
            model.TextStr = result.ElementAt(i);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.TextStr))
            {
                ITextAnalyticsAPI client = this.GetTextAnalyzeClient(new AsyncHandler());
                model.LanguageAnalyzeResult = client.DetectLanguage(
                    new BatchInput(
                        new List<Input>()
                        {
                            new Input(i.ToString(),model.TextStr)
                        }));
                model.SentimentAnalyzeResult = client.Sentiment(
                    new MultiLanguageBatchInput(
                        new List<MultiLanguageInput>()
                        {
                            new MultiLanguageInput(
                                model.LanguageAnalyzeResult.Documents[0].DetectedLanguages[0].Iso6391Name,
                                i.ToString(),
                                model.TextStr)
                        }));
                data.Add(model);
            }
        }
        return Json(data);
    }
```

This is the GetTextAnalyzeClient method:

```
private ITextAnalyticsAPI GetTextAnalyzeClient(DelegatingHandler handler)
    {
        string key = configuration.GetSection("CognitiveServices")["TextAnalytics:ServiceKey"];
        ITextAnalyticsAPI client = new TextAnalyticsAPI(handlers: handler);
        client.SubscriptionKey = key;
        client.AzureRegion = Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.TextAnalytics.Models.AzureRegions.Westus;
        return client;
    }
```

And this is the AsyncHandler class:

```
class AsyncHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
    HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Call the inner handler.
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        return response;
    }
}
```

I tested at different ports and same issue, on localhost runs well and when I publish it throws the exception.
Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log onto the server that IIS is hosted on and try telneting to 40.112.254.71 on 443.  If you don't get a response, that means the traffic is being block (networking rules) and is not dependent on your app.

If a response does occur but after a bit of time, make sure your response timeout is adequately set:

```
<aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:20:00" processPath=“%LAUNCHER_PATH%” arguments=“%LAUNCHER_ARGS%” stdoutLogEnabled=“false” stdoutLogFile=“.\logs\stdout”     />
```

Comment: I tried, didn't work. Is this for outgoing or incoming requests? I found it sets the time for incoming requests to IIS not for outgoing and wait for response.

Comment: @g4b0.88 Did you first try telnetting?  If you can't telnet, no amount of response timeout configuration will matter.

Comment: In my dev machine (where I run the project with IIS express) I installed the IIS 7, in the IIS Express I got no issues, but when deployed to IIS7 there's where I got that error. And no, I didn't try to telnet, how to do that?